# Unable to display the full image in datagridview cell

Tags: c#, .net, image, datagridview

I have data grid view with columns product name and product image and I am populating these values coming from database...

i am using winforms  desktop application.....

my problem is I am not able to showing the image in datagridview cell properly ..see the diagram below[image: total grid view image]

i want to display this image in actual product image  column for every cell in that column  [image: actual image need to show in every row]

this task is very simple in webforms by using datalist  control    but i dont know how to display full image in grid view cell

can any one help on this....

many thanks.......

and this is where i am binding the datagridview by using linq query..

```
      private void EquipmentFinder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

        var products = from prods in abc.products
                       select new
                       {
                           productid = prods.product_Id,   //0                            
                           productname =  prods.product_Name, //1
                           productimage = prods.product_Image, //2
                           productprice = prods.product_Price,//3
                           productdescr = prods.product_Description, //4

                       };
        productbindingsource.DataSource = products;
        productgridview.DataSource = productbindingsource;
        productgridview.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        productgridview.Columns[3].Visible = false;
        productgridview.Columns[4].Visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the column's ImageLayout to the Stretch value to resolve this problem.

**UPDATE:** use the following code to change the ImageLayout property:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i ++)
                if(dataGridView1.Columns[i] is DataGridViewImageColumn) {
                    ((DataGridViewImageColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[i]).ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;
                    break;
                }
```

Comment: I am not defining columns from designer i am just binding details from database using linq query

Comment: how to find the gridviewimagecolumn .. i dint touch the designer.cs see my updated code..

Comment: paste my code below this one: productgridview.Columns[4].Visible = false;  The DataGridViewImageColumn is a type declared in the  System.Windows.Forms namespace.  Please also refer to the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn.aspx

Comment: thanq its working now ... is it possible to increase the width and height of the cell like medium sized square box....would you pls give suggestions ...

Comment: it does not working i have  done like this   productgridview.RowTemplate.Height = 200;

Comment: its not working .....would you pls suggest any other way to increase the width and height of each cell

Answer (score 0):

Set DataGridViewImageColumn.ImageLayout property to DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom

If you set to "Stretch" your image will be inproportionally scaled to fit whole cell. And that is probably not what you want.

Set to zoom to have *The graphic is uniformly enlarged until it fills the width or height of the containing cell.*

By default the value is set to "Normal": *The graphic is displayed centered using its native resolution.*

Answer (score 0):

first right click on grid go to properties of grid in that you will get column (collection) properties click on that. click on image column in that go in appearance-image layout-and choose stretch property you can also increase size of your image column.
its really helpful in that case .you have do not need for such type code.